# Not able to produce and consume kafka message from my local machine to ubuntu VM

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform, kafka-python, confluent-kafka-python

I am trying to produce kafka message from my local machine to Ubuntu vm.

Telnet commad says successfully connected to host.

```
PS C:\Users\harshal> Telnet harshal-VirtualBox 9092
Successfully connected to Host: "harshal-VirtualBox" on Port: "9092"

broker.properties:
request.timeout.ms=1200000
max.block.ms=1200000

server.properties:
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://harshal-VirtualBox:9092,PLAINTEXT://192.168.43.171:9092
```

I am using following code, This code is running fine on the Ubuntu vm but giving me error when i try to execute same from host machine.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer,KafkaConsumer
from time import sleep

producer =KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['harshal-VirtualBox:9092'],api_version=(0,10,1))
for e in range(10):
    producer.send('TestTopicNew',b'sending from host ')
    sleep(3)
```

getting
**KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.**

following is the debug log.

```
DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:Starting the Kafka producer
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name connections-closed
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name connections-created
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name select-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name io-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bufferpool-wait-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name batch-size
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name compression-rate
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name queue-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name produce-throttle-time
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name records-per-request
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bytes

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KafkaTimeoutError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-157f243dc84c> in <module>
     10 
     11 producer =KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['harshal-VirtualBox:9092'],api_version=(0,10,1))
---> 12 producer.send('TestTopicNew',b'sending from host')
     13 

C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\kafka.py in send(self, topic, value, key, headers, partition, timestamp_ms)
    562         key_bytes = value_bytes = None
    563         try:
--> 564             self._wait_on_metadata(topic, self.config['max_block_ms'] / 1000.0)
    565 
    566             key_bytes = self._serialize(

C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\kafka.py in _wait_on_metadata(self, topic, max_wait)
    689             if not metadata_event.is_set():
    690                 raise Errors.KafkaTimeoutError(
--> 691                     "Failed to update metadata after %.1f secs." % (max_wait,))
    692             elif topic in self._metadata.unauthorized_topics:
    693                 raise Errors.TopicAuthorizationFailedError(topic)

KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.


DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name record-retries
INFO:kafka.producer.kafka:Closing the Kafka producer with 4294967.0 secs timeout.
WARNING:kafka.client:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out after 30000 ms. Closing connection.
WARNING:kafka.client:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out after 30000 ms. Closing connection.
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name errors
WARNING:kafka.client:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out after 30000 ms. Closing connection.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError: Request timed out after 30000 ms
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError: Request timed out after 30000 ms
WARNING:kafka.client:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out after 30000 ms. Closing connection.
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name record-size-max
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError: Request timed out after 30000 ms
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.053733828642659076 after 1 failures
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.0555060173039363 after 1 failures
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError: Request timed out after 30000 ms
DEBUG:kafka.producer.sender:Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:Kafka producer started
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.04056800940753716 after 1 failures
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.05091141786347146 after 1 failures
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:Requesting metadata update for topic TestTopicNew
DEBUG:kafka.producer.sender:Beginning shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initiating connection to node bootstrap-0 at harshal-VirtualBox:9092
DEBUG:kafka.producer.sender:Shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread has completed.
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received
DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:The Kafka producer has closed.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bytes-sent
ERROR:kafka.conn:Connection attempt to <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out
ERROR:kafka.conn:Connection attempt to <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. KafkaConnectionError: timeout
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name bytes-received
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. KafkaConnectionError: timeout
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.10767298112773331 after 2 failures
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name request-latency
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.08064906006470171 after 2 failures
ERROR:kafka.conn:Connection attempt to <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name node-bootstrap-0.bytes-sent
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. KafkaConnectionError: timeout
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name node-bootstrap-0.bytes-received
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.08617990914810844 after 2 failures
DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name node-bootstrap-0.latency
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [unspecified None]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: established TCP connection
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew']) to node bootstrap-0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew'])

DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: established TCP connection
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: creating new socket
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: established TCP connection
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew']) to node bootstrap-0
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: established TCP connection
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew'])
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic']) to node bootstrap-0
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew'])
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic'])
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic', 'TestTopicNew']) to node bootstrap-0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic', 'TestTopicNew'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic', 'TestTopicNew'])
WARNING:kafka.client:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out after 30000 ms. Closing connection.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError: Request timed out after 30000 ms
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.052615947599434616 after 1 failures
WARNING:kafka.client:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out after 30000 ms. Closing connection.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError: Request timed out after 30000 ms
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.046722132029283756 after 1 failures
WARNING:kafka.client:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out after 30000 ms. Closing connection.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError: Request timed out after 30000 ms
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.04573278045317557 after 1 failures
WARNING:kafka.client:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out after 30000 ms. Closing connection.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing connection. [Error 7] RequestTimedOutError: Request timed out after 30000 ms
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.04625942805975036 after 1 failures
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: established TCP connection
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew']) to node bootstrap-0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew'])
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: established TCP connection

INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew']) to node bootstrap-0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopicNew'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: established TCP connection
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic']) to node bootstrap-0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: connecting to harshal-VirtualBox:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: established TCP connection
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic', 'TestTopicNew']) to node bootstrap-0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic', 'TestTopicNew'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=harshal-VirtualBox:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['TestTopic', 'TestTopicNew'])
```

Comment: "This code is running fine", but you get an error?

Comment: this code is running fine on my vm but when i try to replicate this from the host machine i am getting the error.

Comment: Your host machine would have no DNS entry for the VM, so it cannot reach it using `harshal-VirtualBox:9092`. Do you really need a VM, though? A Kafka Docker image would be easier for development purposes

Comment: >Telnet harshal-VirtualBox 9092
>Successfully connected to Host: "harshal-VirtualBox" on Port: "9092", i have modified host file.   this i have used port forwarding for the same and above powershell coomd says it is connected successfully. and yes i need vm as i am doing POC to present to customer with limited resources,

Comment: Docker can also have limited resources of cpu and memory constraints. You also advertised 192.168.43.171, so what happens when you connect to it?

Comment: This is the ip of my Host machine i added just to check if it works but no it still gets disconnected from the socket

Comment: IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> timed out after 30000 ms. Closing connection.

Comment: 1) You need to open a port from the VM to the host 2) You need to `advertise` a routable IP from the VM to the host via the Kafka properties.... The easier way to do this would just be run the code in the VM... Dealing with a VM on a single machine with code also running on it will not emulate a cloud environment

Comment: if you see this i already open port to vm and successfully connected to it PS C:\Users\harshal> Telnet harshal-VirtualBox 9092
Successfully connected to Host: "harshal-VirtualBox" on Port: "9092"

Comment: Did you edit your /etc/hosts file for your VM to be discoverable by name? If so, why?